# CMake install destination bin equivalent for Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, environment-variables

On Linux I configured CMake to install output in the `bin` folder.

Then I can call the executable in a terminal whatever the current directory is.

I did:

```
Install(TARGETS ... DESTINATION bin)
```

On Windows, it doesn't work. It's telling me:

> 'whatever' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

What would be the equivalent destination for Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate to ["What is the equivalent of the bin directory for Windows?"](https://superuser.com/questions/983138/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-bin-directory-for-windows). I don't feel this question being CMake specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike Linux, Windows has no *common* directory for installing *runnable files* into it.

If your project contains runnable files, you may place them anywhere under the project's installation prefix (which in turn looks like `C:/Program Files/<Package name>`): you may place runnable files directly under installation prefix or into `bin/` subdirectory or whatever else.

For making a file runnable just by name, you need to add a directory with the file to *PATH* environment variable.

I am unsure whether CMake has support for automatically modifying the *PATH* variable on plain installing of a CMake project.

However, when packaging your project with [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cpack.1.html), [some generators](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackPackageGenerators) allows you to create a project's installer with automatic *PATH* updating. E.g. for the NSIS generator, see the *CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH* and *CPACK_NSIS_EXECUTABLES_DIRECTORY* variables.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at cpack.
I'll need to install nsis but does the users need to install it as well to use the cpack file that I'll generate ?

Comment: do you have any tutorial for cpack ? because I don't get how to use it.
I don't get it. 
I added 
set(CPACK_GENERATOR NSIS)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "MyLib")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "MyLib - CPack Component Installation Example")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "CPack Component Example")
SET(CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH ON)
Include(CPACK)
and then what do I do ?
I still do the config/generation using cmake-gui and build using visual studio ? and after that ?